# Excel Import in C# - Missing column error

Tags: c#, excel-import

I have an API that I use to import an Excel spreadsheet into the system and it works correctly although it does not handle missing columns and I am not sure how and at what point I can do that.

I'll give an example first:
I have an Excel spreadsheet (.xlsx) with 4 columns A, B, C, and D all containing text data, and what I would like to achieve is

1. When the user import the file with A, B, and C (D has been removed), it is correctly updating the row and keep the value in column D untouched

Client side I have an API call that looks like this:

```
this.service.PostFormData<HttpEvent<any>>("v1/ui/importExcel", formData)
```

where formData is of type FormData ([API FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData))

On the backend I do something like that:

```
HttpFileCollection files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

foreach (string fileKey in files.AllKeys)
{
            HttpPostedFile file = files[fileKey];
            ISheet sheet = ImportHelper.GetImport(file);
}

public static ISheet GetImport(HttpPostedFile file)
{
    ISheet sheet;

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file.InputStream); <--- error
    sheet = workbook.GetSheetAt(0);

    return sheet;
}
```

As soon as it tries to convert the InputStream into a workbook it triggers an error (only when a column has been removed from the imported spreadsheet).

The code is within a try & catch (Exception e) although e comes back as blank.

Can you guys help out with that? Also, let me know if there is any better Exception type I can use to get a decent error message

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: And - you could try to copy the stream to a memory stream first instead of using it directly. HttpBased streams sometimes lacks a "seek" implementation, which can be required in some cases.

Comment: I don't get any useful error - as I mentioned I am using the general error type handle (Exception e) and 'e' comes back as '{""}'. I'll look into copying the stream first, before trying the conversion. Thanks

Comment: Good luck... It is a bit of a long shot though...